# Remove black residue/mold on bathroom caulking

Tags: bathroom, mold, caulking

I have black residue developing along the seams in my bathroom (standing shower). The residue seems to be growing on the white caulking done along the seams. I tried to remove it using the "Scrubbing Bubbles Bathroom Cleaner" but it did not work.

Is there another way to remove it without damaging the caulking?

I do have similar black spots appearing near my kitchen sink and bathroom sinks, but not as big as in the shower area.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no simple solution for this.

One of the issues you might have is that these locations are damp by nature ; and they might be poorly lit. Damp/Dark = Mold growth.

Now in the modern world of LED lighting people will say it is not poorly lit so it is not dark.
 Point well taken EXCEPT that LED light lacks the UV rays needed to inhibit and kill mold growth. This is why I have Halogen Lights above my shower and not LED lights. So now instead of having a terrible mold growth and cleaning problem every day, I have an easy to keep clean area with no visible mold growth anywhere.